# Protege; infer that if two apartments are located in the same address, then they are in the same building

Tags: object, properties, type-inference, protege

I am pretty new at building ontologies in Protege. I am doing a simplified real estate ontology. I have an object property called "isLocatedIn" (actually my ontology is in spanish, so that is not the real name, but lets keep it simple) with domain RealEstate and range RealEstate or Address. You can say that an Apartment "isLocatedIn some Address" or that IsLocatedIn some RealEstate (in this last case it should be an apartment building.
What i want is the reasoner to infer that if a building and an apartment are located in the same address, then the apartment is located in the same address. It sounds as simple as transitivity, but it actually does not work.
Another thing i would like to know is if i can do a DL query that returns builings that are in the same address, i can figure it, it should be easy to say something like Buildings and isLocatedIn some Self.Address or something like that, or chaining objectproperties to the point to reach Self, something like Buildings and isLocatedIn o inverse(isLocatedIn) some Self.
Im not sure if i can explain what i want to do
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you provide your minimal ontology illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I already find a way to do it using SWRL rules. I thing there might be another way around using property chains, but i didnt go deep into it.
The way i did it required to install a plugin to work with SWRL rules and then go to Windows -> Tabs  and select SWRL tab.
Then it is pretty easy, just some google to see the syntax and edit some premade googled rules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).